# ImportError when importing 'fastai.core' in Google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am encountering an `ImportError` when trying to import the 'fastai.core' module in a Google Colab notebook. The code snippet where the error occurs is in the section titled "Upload the pre-trained model" of my Colab notebook.

I have tried appending the required directories to `sys.path`, including both the repository directory and the 'fastai' directory within the repository. However, I still receive the `ModuleNotFoundError` with the message `'No module named 'fastai.core''`.

I have verified that the file '/content/DeOldify/fastai/core.py' exists in the repository and have also confirmed that the Python version (3.6 or later) is compatible with the 'fastai' library.

Here is the code snippet that triggers the error:

```py
from deoldify.visualize import *
!mkdir 'models'
try:
  !rm -rf models/ColorizeVideo_gen.pth
  !gdown https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1-3ONnPYcX9fOqnY-pUKYGJOd6XeFon9X -O ./models/ColorizeVideo_gen.pth
except BaseException:
  !rm -rf models/ColorizeVideo_gen.pth
  !wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/336vn9y4qwyg9yz/ColorizeVideo_gen.pth?dl=0 -O ./models/ColorizeVideo_gen.pth
colorizer = get_video_colorizer()
clear_output()
```

I have also included a link to the full Colab notebook for reference: [Colab Notebook Link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1dxYc6BBtUwOaIl6YHgHsoORel-8nhJNP#scrollTo=XHjidueePj9g)

Any suggestions on how to resolve this import error and successfully import the 'fastai.core' module would be greatly appreciated.